Why is ubuntu throwing me out to the log in screen?
I am currently using the Ubuntu 23.10 and sometimes while I am using the computer with no big load of operation it freezes and the login screen appears. Sometimes I am coping large amount of files or files very big and also happens. It something that occurs 3 or 4 times in a day. Any idea of what is happening or how can I know what is causing it?

I do have a swap. My ram is 16 GB and the swap partition is 4 GB. Originally was 32, but I reduce it because it was too much. The problem also happened with the 32 GB of swap.
